# MacOs Monterey: How to make it to remember my login password and avoid asking me every time

Tags: macos, keychain, macos-monterey

I have a MacBook Pro with M1 chip. This is my first time using Mac. I was a Windows User in x86 intel platform.

Using Keychain Access app, every time I do copy password to clipboard on an item, MacOs Monterey request me my login password. Is there any way to remember it and not being requesting me every time? Also it requests my login password in some other situations.

Comment: Welcome to the Mac! It’s basically the same for these items as it is in windows. Whether you are trying to use the built-in Windows password (credential?) manager or copy a password back from a browser like chrome, you need to enter your login password again. The other times that you are usually prompted is when you are installing new software or reconfiguring system settings, and again that’s like UAC in Windows which prompts you for your password when doing the same operations.

Comment: @jimtut Thanks for the info